# Nested list initialization does not match constructor taking initializer_list as second argument

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, initializer-list, list-initialization

I am developing data structure able to describe semantics of some XML files in C++. Idea is to check presence and/or proper sequence of various elements while storing text they contain into QHash object with QString id's (based on element names, but customizable) as keys.

As XML supports nesting I would like to be able to mirror this nesting. So each XML element is described either by "name" and (optional) "id", what means it is the final leaf and it's text will get parsed, or "name" and list of other element descriptors, what means there should be these nested elements inside the current one.

As there will be plenty of such semantic schemes, I would like to have the code describing their individual instances really compact.

My idea was to have an class, that describes one element and can be constructed via c++ std::initializer_list literals, what I hoped to support nesting implicitly. Various overloaded constructors than can set various specific details later on.

I got almost there, but now got stuck. Even though constructor with signature `constructor(std::initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode >);`
gets called normally for every nested curly braces, simillar signature constructor `constructor(QString, std::initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode >);`
gets never called, even if I place constructs like
`{ "xyz", { {"abc", "123"}, {"def","456"} } }`

as the initializer literal.

Please take a look at the following code snippets, separated from the testing code and help me to understand if:
1. This is a normal c++11 behavior and std::initializer_list does not support such nesting combined with other data type parameters.
2. This is the matter of implementation (bug ;) ) in gcc (I am using version 4.9.1 (Debian 4.9.1-1))
3. I am overlooking some really stupid detail in code syntax/semantics.

Class declaration (excerpt of relevant constructors):

```
class ProtocolDescriptorTestNode {

public:
    ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(const ProtocolDescriptorTestNode&);

    ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(std::initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode > init); // 1
    ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(QString name, std::initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode > init); // 2
    ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(QString name, QString id, enum eElementMode = modeDefault); // 4
    ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(QString name, enum eElementMode = modeDefault); //5

    ~ProtocolDescriptorTestNode() {}

     QString name, id;
     tProtocolDescriptorTestList list;
};
```

Definitions of relevant constructors:

```
ProtocolDescriptorTestNode::ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(std::initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode> init)
{
    qDebug() << "*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 1 *** ";
    qDebug() << init.size();
    for(ProtocolDescriptorTestNode x : init) {
        qDebug() << x.name << x.id;
    }
}

ProtocolDescriptorTestNode::ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(QString name, std::initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode> init) {
    qDebug() << "*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 2 *** ";
    qDebug() << init.size();
    for(ProtocolDescriptorTestNode x : init) {
        qDebug() << x.name << x.id;
    }
}

ProtocolDescriptorTestNode::ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(QString name, QString id, enum eElementMode) :
    name(name),
    id(id)
{
    qDebug() << "*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 4 *** ";
    qDebug() << name << id;
}

ProtocolDescriptorTestNode::ProtocolDescriptorTestNode(QString name, enum eElementMode)  :
    name(name),
    id("***")
{
    qDebug() << "*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 5 *** ";
    qDebug() << name << id;
}
```

Testing object instance:
(notice: implicit/explicit datatype conversion char * / QString does not make difference)

```
ProtocolDescriptorTestNode groupOther
({
     {QString("name1"),"groupOther1"},
     {"name2","groupOther2"},

     { QString("B"), {
        {"name3","groupOther3"},
        {
             {"intra1","a"},
             {QString("intra2")}
         },
        {"name4","groupOther4"}
     } }

 });
```

And relevant part of debug output, showing that the part of the initialization near the `"B"` literal is treated as `node(QString("B")` and `node(std::initializer_list)` concatenated, not `node(QString("B"), std::initializer_list)` as was my intention:

```
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 4 *** 
"name1" "groupOther1"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 4 *** 
"name2" "groupOther2"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 5 *** 
"B" "***"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 4 *** 
"name3" "groupOther3"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 4 *** 
"intra1" "a"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 5 *** 
"intra2" "***"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 1 *** 
1
"intra2" "***"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 1 *** 
2
"intra1" "a"
"" ""
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 4 *** 
"name4" "groupOther4"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 1 *** 
3
"name3" "groupOther3"
"" ""
"name4" "groupOther4"
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 1 *** 
2
"B" "***"
"" ""
*** CONSTRUCTOR CALLED - 1 *** 
3
"name1" "groupOther1"
"name2" "groupOther2"
"" ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that if a type has a constructor with a single parameter of type `initializer_list` (or has additional parameters, but the remaining have default arguments), **list initialization will always prefer that constructor** over other constructors (*§13.3.1.7/1 [over.match.list]*). With that in mind, let's work our way through your initialization.

At the outermost level you have a braced-init-list that contains 3 elements:

```
{
    {QString("name1"),"groupOther1"}  // element 1
    {"name2","groupOther2"}           // element 2
    { QString("B"), ... }             // element 3
}
```

`ProtocolDescriptorTestNode` has a constructor that takes a single argument of type `initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode>`. Because of the rule I mentioned earlier, the compiler is going to try to convert each of these 3 elements to a `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode`.

Each of these elements are themselves braced-init-lists, so an attempt will be made to match the `initializer_list` constructor first.

---

Consider the first element:

```
{QString("name1"),"groupOther1"}
```

To convert this to an `initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode>`, the second argument would require 2 user defined conversions, first to `QString` and then to `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode`, which is not allowed. So other constructors of `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode` are considered, and it matches *constructor 4*.

> Note that behavior would be different if the first element had been
>
> ```
>  {QString("name1"),QString("groupOther1")}
> ```
>
> In this case, each element of the braced-init-list would match *constructor 5* to create a `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode` instance, and the two would then form an `initializer_list<ProtocolDescriptorTestNode>` and match *constructor 1*.

---

The next element is

```
{"name2","groupOther2"}
```

which again matches *constructor 4* for the same reason as the last case.

---

The third element is

```
 { QString("B"), 
    {
       {"name3","groupOther3"},  // constructor 4
       {
          {"intra1","a"},        // constructor 4
          {QString("intra2")}    // constructor 1
       },                        // constructor 1
       {"name4","groupOther4"}   // constructor 4
    }                            // constructor 1
 }                               // constructor 1
```

The first sub-element is implicitly convertible to `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode` (matching *constructor 5*), and the second sub-element, itself a braced-init-list, is also convertible to `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode` (matching *constructor 1*), because each of the sub-elements within this braced-init-list are themselves implicitly convertible to `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode` by matching various constructors, as indicated by the comments above.

Thus *constructor 2* is never matched.

---

After that long winded explanation, the fix to your problem is surprisingly simple, and hinted at in the explanation for the first element. The reason *element 3* matches the `initializer_list` constructor is because both its sub-elements are implicitly convertible to `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode`. So, replace `QString("B")` with `"B"`. Now its conversion to `ProtocolDescriptorTestNode` requires two user defined conversions, and the `initializer_list` constructor is no longer viable. Other constructors will be considered, and *constructor 2* will be matched.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbd82001fa573011)

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast, accurate and very supportive answer. Based on it I was able to continue my development almost in no time.
(In fact I was so close to the solution, just as it was very long day and I posted my question at 3am local time I lost confidence in my idea. So your description confirming and very clearly describing what I was roughly expecting myself was exactly what I needed to find at morning :D )

Comment: JFYI: Another thank goes for showing me the Coliru Live demo thing, which will be great for collaborative discussions. Just when I tried to modify your code a bit, it did not compile out-of-box, stating "Internal server error" (huh). But I managed to find that instead of a.cpp (auto-provided in compile line after pushing "Edit" button) I have to substitute full path (Archive1/.../a.out) as found in Q&A and voilà, it compiled like a charm. Do not know, if you can modify this before using the Share button, but you can eventually take a look at it.

Comment: @pmendl Coliru is awesome, but has been having some stability issues recently. If you wait a while and then give it another go, it usually is back up and running.